# SQL 'partition by order by' turns count() into rank()?

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure out how to use `partition by` properly, and looking for a brief explanation to the following results. (I apologize for including the test data without proper SQL code.)

Example 1: Counts the IDs (e.g. shareholders) for each company and adds it to the original data frame (as "newvar").

```
select ID, company, 
count(ID) over(partition by company) as newvar
from testdata;
```

Example 2: When I now add `order by shares` count() somehow seems to turn into rank(), so that the output is merely a ranking variable.

```
select ID, company, 
count(ID) over(partition by company order by shares) as newvar
from testdata;
```

I thought order by just orders the data, but it seems to have an impact on "newvar".

Is there a simple explanation to this?

Many thanks in advance!

.csv file that contains testdata:

```
ID;company;shares
1;a;10
2;a;20
3;a;70
1;b;50
4;b;10
5;b;10
6;b;30
2;c;80
3;c;10
7;c;10
1;d;20
2;d;30
3;d;25
6;d;10
7;d;15
```

Answer (score 1):

`count()` with an `order by` does a cumulative count.  It is going to turn the value either into `rank()` or `row_number()`, depending on ties in the `shares` value and how the database handles missing windows frames (`rows between` or `range between`).

If you want to just order the data, then the `order by` should be after the `from` clause:

```
select ID, company, 
       count(ID) over(partition by company) as newvar
from testdata
order by shares;
```